A mystery in TeX. Output related to an empty line?
In one example, I get an output with the table, in the other example, I do not. The only diffence is the empty line after
\def\ault{Error}%

How may this be explained?
  %TeX-File
\TeX%
\input plipsum%
\parindent=0pt%
\hoffset-0in%
\hsize=6.5in%from plain.tex
\vsize=8.9in%from plain.tex
\raggedright%
\newcount\columns
\newcount\column%
\column=1%
\newcount\limit
\limit=20%
\newdimen\csize%
%defining tables
\columns=5%number of columns
 \def\ault{Error}%
\csize=\hsize \divide\csize by\columns%
%end of calculation
\def\col#1{\vtop{\hsize=\csize #1\vskip\baselineskip}\advance\column by 1 \ifnum\column>\columns \ault\else \fi }
\hbox{\col{\lipsum1}\col{\lipsum1}\col{\lipsum1}\col{\lipsum1}}
\bye

Second
    %TeX-File
\TeX%
\input plipsum%
\parindent=0pt%
\hoffset-0in%
\hsize=6.5in%from plain.tex
\vsize=8.9in%from plain.tex
\raggedright%
\newcount\columns
\newcount\column%
\column=1%
\newcount\limit
\limit=20%
\newdimen\csize%
%defining tables
\columns=5%number of columns
 \def\ault{Error}%

\csize=\hsize \divide\csize by\columns%
%end of calculation
\def\col#1{\vtop{\hsize=\csize #1\vskip\baselineskip}\advance\column by 1 \ifnum\column>\columns \ault\else \fi }
\hbox{\col{\lipsum1}\col{\lipsum1}\col{\lipsum1}\col{\lipsum1}}
\bye


well you are first typesetting TeX, then you load plipsum which adds lots of spaces, then you typeset the hbox in the same paragraph (and so get an overfull hbox). With the empty line the hbox is in a new paragraph and so the spaces from plispum no longer matter. load plispum first if you want the box to be on the same line as TeX.

@Ulrike Fischer
Loading plipsum first leads to more trouble. Adding an empty line (paragraph) before the \hbox solves the problem. And, as expectable, an empty line after \Tex does the same. But, to extend the question: Why is the table not displayed at all, if there are no fitting paragraphs?

It is displayed far on the right outside the page border after all the spaces from plipsum
